# filter/interpolate x,y points to specific # of points, with a list of specific points to include

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, filtering, interpolation

[image]I need some help filtering/interpolating some data in python.

I have a list of x,y points (about 1500 pairs) that I want to interpolate down to 500 points while retaining as much detail as possible (not just dropping 2/3 of the points).

I also want to include a list of x points that the resulting dataset would have to include.

Does anyone have any idea how I could approach this?

Comment: I think what you need is downsampling, not interpolation. use numpy indexing : `arr2 = arr[1::3]`

Comment: @Masoud, this action will result in dropping 2/3 of the points

Comment: @Derek Eden, can you tell if x-es are evenly distributed? If so, then you could simply take a mean of every 3 consecutive points like ```arr.reshape(-1,3).mean(axis=-1)```

Comment: @tstanisl unfortunately they are not..some are close together some are further apart, but I appreciate the suggestion..I've added a figure to my OP to better describe what I'm trying to do..potentially something to do with local mins/maxs?

Comment: It depends on what you consider "detail" and what you actually want to drop. i Would suggest first running your data through a function that generate the 500 x coordinates that you think are best and than use one of scipy [interpolate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) functions such as [interp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d)

Comment: @DerekEden selection of local extrema will not solve a problem. See 4th "included" point from right on rhe diagram. It is neither maximum nor minimum

Comment: @tstanisl: You are right. I hadn't seen the photo. And I suppose averaging does help, as you mentioned.

Comment: Can you link your dataset?

Comment: this kind of problem is addressed by the [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm). OpenCV  efficiently implements it as [`approxPolyDP`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga0012a5fdaea70b8a9970165d98722b4c)

Answer (score 3):

You can try to filter vertices that are collinear to neighboring vertices.
You can use vector cross-product for this check.

Let p0,p1,p2 be consecutive points in `arr`. Let A be a vector pointing from p1 to p0, let B be a vector pointing from p1 to p2. If cross-product of those vectors is zero then the vectors lay on the same line and the middle point can be dropped.

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# First generate dataset similar to yours
# Generate joint points
x0, y0 =np.random.uniform(size=(2,10))
x0.sort() # sort if so it can be used by np.interp()

# Next generate sampling points, add joint points to the set
x = np.hstack((x0, np.random.uniform(size=50)));
x.sort() # sort to have meaningful neghbours

# interpolate at xes
y = np.interp(x, x0, y0)

# compute vector A and B
xa = x[:-2]-x[1:-1]
xb=x[2:]-x[1:-1]
ya=y[:-2]-y[1:-1]
yb=y[2:]-y[1:-1]

# compute cross product
cross = xa*yb-xb*ya

# accept only point which cross-product is above threshold, add the first and the last sample, which were omitted in cross-product calculations
mask = np.hstack([True, abs(cross)>1e-9, True])
# uncomment line below in order to spare additional vertices
# mask[indices_to_keep] = True

# select vertices
xs, ys = x[mask], y[mask]

# draw result
plt.plot(x, y, '-o')
plt.plot(xs, ys, 'x')
plt.show()
```

The result is:
[image]

Comment: sorry I'm away from my computer with the dataset on it..will test this code on it when I can and provide the dataset...this looks very promising though